# Reset reviews of Chrome Extension on Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is it possible to reset the reviews by users of a Chrome Extension, perhaps by publishing another version of the extension?

I'm curious because I'm considering publishing a rough MVP of my Extension and iterating on it over the coming weeks, but a real consideration is whether the reviews I will get from the rough early version will sink the future, more robust iterations. I've checked the Chrome store's documentation and general Googling but cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, reviews are not tied to a specific version and stay with a particular extension forever. However, you can unpublish that extension and publish it again as a different item, but your users will need to install the new extension.

Comment: once you have the new extension, you might be able to use inline installation from the old one to easily ask old users to migrate.

Comment: No, inline installation is not yet possible from extensions or apps. crbug.com/426912

Comment: Alternatively you can do an onboarding in your extension and ask your user to file bugs on your favorite issue tracker and not on the store. You can tell them that this is developing extension and not all may working properly. However, you shouldn't publish untested extensions to public. You can also use publishing to the tested accounts: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish. You can ask beta users to join the program and only them receive updates of your app.